# Google Recaptcha check timeout due to IPv6 issue - php on IIS

Tags: php, iis, recaptcha, ipv6, ipv4

I'm using google recaptcha v2 on my websites (html / php).

On the server side I am trying to contact google recaptcha to check the user's input:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
```

The line above is not working. It normally just times out. Occasionally it will work though.

**IPv6 is the Issue**

It appears to be an issue with the call to google resolving to IPv6 (from https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/193)

I have tried turning off IPv6 on my internet connection and that makes it work.

How do I fix this issue properly? I don't think I could turn off IPv6 on the servers (we use some shared hosting as well as a VPS). Is there a way to force it to resolve to IPv4?

Thanks!

Comment: That URL works fine on both IPv6 and IPv4. Something else is going on, if it doesn't work for you. Contact your server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that php could not verify the SSL certificate. The IPv4 / IPv6 was a bit of a red herring I think.

Great post here on that: [file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)